# convex function in convex domain has its minimum (or bounded from below)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Prove or disprove the following statement.

> Suppose that $E$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and that
> $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is a convex function. Then $f$ has its minimum. (Or
> $f$ is bounded from below so that it has infimum in $\mathbb R$).

I think the above statement is fairly wrong because of the obvious counterexample :

$f(x)=\frac1x$ is a convex function in a convex set $E=\mathbb R$.
And $f$ has neither a minimum nor an infimum.

Am I right?

Comment: Your $f$ isn't defined at $x=0$. You need to at least restrict the domain to $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, which is no longer convex.

Comment: @kipf You're right. Moreover, my $f$ is convex only if $x>0$. Bad counterexample.

Comment: $f(x) = x$ is convex on $\Bbb R$ and is not bounded below.

Comment: I heard something like the statement above in the context of convex optimization. But I can't find the exact proof of this.

Comment: In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization), it says 'If $f$ is unbounded below over  $C$ or the infimum is not attained, then the optimization problem is said to be unbounded'. I think it means that $f$ is sometimes unbouded from below.

Comment: @MartinR Your're right. So the above condition doesn't guarantees the existence of minimum. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps require that $E$ is bounded and closed.  I added "closed", since even if $f$ is bounded below, its minimum may occur on the boundary of $E$.

Comment: If E were bounded and closed, it would be compact. f being convex, it is conrinuous. So f attains its maximum. And you're saying that the minimum occurs on the boundary? It sounds plausible.

Comment: another nice convex function where the inf is not attained is $f(x) = \exp(x)$.